# Query to determine if ID exists with certain column value across rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I need to write a query for Purchase Orders and get Header and Line data. This is a one to many relationship, where there is one header row `PO_ID` (`PS_PO_HDR`) to one or more associated lines (`PS_PO_LINE`) via the `PO_ID` identifier. I need the query to exclude rows where the `CANCEL_STATUS` is equal to 'X' **UNLESS** that same `PO_ID` and `BUSINESS_UNIT` has other rows with values in `CANCEL_STATUS` other than `X'`.

Essentially I need to be able to query to using the other criteria in my query below (other than the specific `PO_ID` I have meeting this scenario) that will capture the above criteria. If the `PO_ID` / `BUSINESS_UNIT` has a `CANCEL_STATUS` of 'X' on all of it's row(s) then I don't want that `PO_ID` included in the results.

I would want the below `PO_ID` included because even though it does have a row with `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'`, it also has other rows with `CANCEL_STATUS` with other values(other than 'X')

How can I accomplish identifying `PO_ID`'s where this occurs?

[image]

```
SELECT LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT, LINE.PO_ID, LINE.LINE_NBR, LINE.CANCEL_STATUS, LINE.CHANGE_STATUS
FROM PS_PO_LINE LINE
INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR HEADER ON HEADER.BUSINESS_UNIT = LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND HEADER.PO_ID = LINE.PO_ID
--ONLY USING THE FOLLOWING PO_ID FILTER TO ILLUSTRATE THIS EXAMPLE!!
WHERE LINE.PO_ID = 'A010027905'
 AND HEADER.PO_STATUS NOT IN ('C','X','PX')
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the colors in your image are not there by accident and mean something.  It would be helpful to share that meaning.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think he's just highlighted the "X" vs the "C" and "A" values to emphasise his point.  A certain PO could have multiple lines, and each of those lines might have a different CANCEL_STATUS value.  In the case of his example, even though one line has an "X" CANCEL_STATUS value, because the other lines are non-"X", then that PO needs to appear in the query results.  Conversely, if it was the case that every line for that PO had an "X" CANCEL_STATUS value, then that PO should not appear in the query results

Comment: @Craig yes that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the results you're after with something like this

```
SELECT LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT, LINE.PO_ID, LINE.LINE_NBR, LINE.CANCEL_STATUS, LINE.CHANGE_STATUS
FROM PS_PO_LINE LINE
INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR HEADER ON HEADER.BUSINESS_UNIT = LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND HEADER.PO_ID = LINE.PO_ID
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM PS_PO_LINE AS [LineCheck] WHERE [LineCheck].PO_ID = HEADER.PO_ID AND [LineCheck].BUSINESS_UNIT = HEADER.BUSINESS_UNIT AND [LineCheck].CANCEL_STATUS != 'X');
```

Not sure how big your data tables actually are, and what sort of indexing is applied.  If they are very large tables that are not indexed across some of these query columns, you may well need to look at that to ensure acceptable performance

Comment: Also, I couldn't quite tell from your question whether - in the instance where there is at least one PO line that isn't cancelled - you still want to include the cancelled line in the actual output results.  My solution, above, gives your query the logic to decide if it should output a certain PO or not.  I'm sure you'll then be able to add other criteria, as necessary, to achieve your final result

Comment: in that instance I would **not** want to include the cancelled line in the output.

Comment: Gotcha.  So then you're just adding AND LINE.CANCEL_STATUS != 'X' to the end of the query so that those lines are not actually included in the output results

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this. Using an `exists` to filter rows - compare the count of rows per po_id with the count of rows that have status of 'X', if the values are different, let it through.

```
select l.BUSINESS_UNIT, l.PO_ID, l.LINE_NBR, l.CANCEL_STATUS, l.CHANGE_STATUS
from PS_PO_LINE l
inner join PS_PO_HDR h on h.BUSINESS_UNIT = l.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 and h.PO_ID = l.PO_ID
     where exists (
     select * from PS_PO_LINE x
     where x.po_id=l.po_id
     having Count(*) != Sum(case when cancel_status='X' then 1 else 0 end)
 )
```

Comment: Not sure this would work as your answer suggests.  Did you mean to do COUNT(*) != SUM(.... , or otherwise it should be WHERE NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @craig yes you're spot on I had two versions I tested one with exists and not exists, I missed the `!=` copy & paste fail. Have amended!